# How can I run a hive query that will return 0's for count when no record is present on the right side of a join?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, aggregate-functions

I have some time series data that I'd like to group by count of records per minute. This is the closest I can get:

```
select
  2016 as year,
  9 as month,
  dhm.day,
  dhm.hour,
  dhm.min,
  count(case isnotnull(id) when true then 1 else 0 end )
from crdb.dayhourmin dhm
 left  join tracelog
  on  (cast(substr(tracestart, 20, 2) as int) = dhm.min 
  and cast(substr(tracestart, 17, 2) as int) = dhm.hour
  and cast(substr(tracestart, 9 , 2) as int) = dhm.day
  and  substr(tracestart, 12, 4)='2016'
  and substr(tracestart, 5, 3)='Sep' )      
group by      
  dhm.day, dhm.hour, dhm.min

sort by 1,2,3,4,5
```

`tracestart` is a string field. Nothing I can do about that. The `dayhourmin` table contains one entry for every day, hour and minute that can be in a month: 24*60*31 = 44640 rows. However when I run the query above I get a lot of `1` values (about 5k), which tells me that there are a lot of empty values on the right side -- 1 record per minute is very unlikely in this data. If I take out the null check and just get a count, I will get about 39k rows. Sept would be 43200 rows, really, since it only has 30 days, but I'm not gonna worry about that now, I can drop off the last day easily in Excel.

How can I write a query like this so that *every* row in `crdb.dayhourmin` (the time slices) has a row in the output and the count is accurate for every row that is present on the right side of the join?

Is this possible? A script -- that loops each possible value and runs a query and it would sure be faster than flailing away at this SQL all day --seems like the natural choice to me but that would be a big problem to run, unless there's some way to run a script from the `hive` command line and concatenate the output to a file.

Comment: use `count(case isnotnull(id) when true then 1 end)` .. eliminate the else part..because 0's would be counted too..if you eliminate it it would be `null` in case of false and would be counted as 0.

Comment: or you can simply use `count(id)` because `null`s wouldn't be counted.

Comment: well I didn't think that would work but your first comment fixed it